# How can I resize the original versions of all of the images that have already been uploaded?

Tags: media

I have a Drupal 7 site that uses a custom content type that allows users to upload images via the core image field.

Originally, I set the maximum resolution of images to 2048x2048 on the field configuration page.  However, I realized that I only need a resolution of 1024x1024.  I have modified the value of the setting, and new image files are resized appropriately, but the image files that have already been uploaded are still up to 2048 pixels in size.

**What I want to do:**  I would like to resize the image fields that have already been uploaded to a maximum of 1024x1024 as well.

**What I tried:** I made a view of all images and used Views Bulk Operations to re-save all content.  However, this had no effect on the image sizes.